# Eclipse, Scala & Maven - Class files are not generating

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, scala-ide

I converted my scala project in eclipse to use Maven (simply by right clicking on project and Configure Maven build), this created  pom.xml, added right dependency which pulled up required jars from maven repository but whenever i try to compile I don't see class file generating in target\classes folder. However, i see actual source code which is scala files in respective directory under target\classes folder. I am not sure why it is copying source files in target\classes folder.

Another wierd thing, is if i open individual scala file in eclipse and do some code changes, then it automatically builds that class file, however i have 1000+ scala files, so not a feasible option.

I tried all options such as Eclipse - Clean & Build, but nothing works, i tried even using maven build inside eclipse but it always comes up with this message "Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date", i cleaned up my target directory but still an issue.

I would appreciate any help in this regard.

Thanks in advance

I am using Scala Eclipse IDE 
-Scala IDE build of Eclipse SDK
Build id: 3.0.4-2.11-20140520-1158-Typesafe

```
Content of Pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>notmaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>notmaven</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>C:\projectsomu\notmaven\src</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>C:\projectsomu\notmaven\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>C:\projectsomu\notmaven\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>C:\projectsomu\notmaven\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>C:\projectsomu\notmaven\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>C:\projectsomu\notmaven\src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>C:\projectsomu\notmaven\src\test\resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>C:\projectsomu\notmaven\target</directory>
    <finalName>notmaven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.3</source>
              <target>1.2</target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.3</source>
              <target>1.2</target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.3</source>
          <target>1.2</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\projectsomu\notmaven\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\projectsomu\notmaven\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>C:\projectsomu\notmaven\target\site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>C:\projectsomu\notmaven\target\site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: Could you share the content of your `pom.xml`?

Comment: updated question with content of pom.xml.. thanks

Comment: It seems you have not added the appropriate parts to `pom.xml`. See: http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/m2eclipse/#Import_an_existing_Scala_Maven_project

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You [should add](http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/m2eclipse/#Import_an_existing_Scala_Maven_project) the following plugin to your maven configuration (`pom.xml`) and reconfigure the project.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
        <goal>testCompile</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

You [should also add](http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/m2eclipse/#Install_m2eclipse-scala) the m2e-scala plugin from its [update site](http://alchim31.free.fr/m2e-scala/update-site).

Comment: Hello! can you please specify what does it mean to reconfigure the project? (I'm working with IntelliJ)

Comment: @nicola it is equivalent of Maven/Reimport from the context menu of the project.