# Running Scala code in Eclipse with Maven enabled

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven

I am trying to run some trivial Scala code in Eclipse but I am not able to get it working when Maven is enabled.

I start by creating a Scala project in Eclipse and then I add an object with the following code:

```
object HelloSpark extends App 
{
    println("Hello, world!")
}
```

I then use "Run As>>Scala Application" to successfully execute the above code:

> Hello, world!

I then enable Maven by clicking on "Configure>>Convert to Maven Project". While the ensuing build is successful, the "Run As>>Scala Application" option no longer comes up. Using the previously created launch configuration results in the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class HelloSpark

Trying the answer for [Eclipse, Scala & Maven - Class files are not generating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28047662/eclipse-scala-maven-class-files-are-not-generating?rq=1) did not help in my case.

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I don't understand why enabling Maven changes the way Scala code is run.

Thanks.

Edit: Here is the pom.xml that was automatically generated when I converted the above to a Maven project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>HelloSpark</groupId>
  <artifactId>HelloSpark</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out simply converting the Eclipse project to a Maven project is not enough. Maven has to know it's a Scala project and build it accordingly.

I followed the instructions at http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-with-maven.html and now I have a working project with running code. It's important to generate a Maven archetype first and then convert it to an Eclipse project before importing it into Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you have a maven project, the project is build with maven. Therefore you need a pom.xml file where you define how to build the project and so on. Are you aware of this, did you configure a pom.xml? Without the correct pom file you cannot build and run the app.

So without a correct maven build, you will not have a class file. Therefore you are getting this error: `Error: Could not find or load main class HelloSpark`

Comment: Converting the project to a Mven project automatically added a pom.xml file. I have added it to my post as an edit.